# How do i add two lists' elements into one list?

Tags: python, list

For example, I have a list like this:

```
list1 = ['good', 'bad', 'tall', 'big']

list2 = ['boy', 'girl', 'guy', 'man']
```

and I want to make a list like this:

```
list3 = ['goodboy', 'badgirl', 'tallguy', 'bigman']
```

I tried something like these:

```
list3=[]
list3 = list1 + list2
```

but this would only contain the value of `list1`

So I used `for` :

```
list3 = []
for a in list1:
 for b in list2:
  c = a + b
  list3.append(c)
```

but it would result in too many lists(in this case, 4*4 = 16 of them)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions with `zip`:

```
list3 = [a + b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

`zip` produces a list of tuples by combining elements from iterables you give it. So in your case, it will return pairs of elements from `list1` and `list2`, up to whichever is exhausted first.

Comment: In hindsight, I would probably recommend something similar to `map` solution from one of the other answers: `map(operator.add, list1, list2)`. Using binary+ functions with `map` is lesser known feature than list comprehensions, though.

Comment: @Xion Wrong, that's not readable at all compared to a list comprehension and should **only** be used as a form of micro-optimization if dealing with a very large dataset where `map(add, list1, list2)` will perform much faster. However in this case, your initial answer was correct.

Comment: I don't know what the "operator.add" or "add" objects you are talking about are, but this works for me, and seems a little shorter:  map(''.join,zip(list1,list2))

Answer (score 1):

A solution using a loop that you try is one way, this is more beginner friendly than Xions solution.

```
list3 = []
for index, item in enumerate(list1):
    list3.append(list1[index] + list2[index])
```

This will also work for a shorter solution. Using map() and lambda, I prefer this over zip, but thats up to everyone

```
list3 = map(lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y), list1, list2);
```

Comment: Why use enumerate if you aren't using `item`?

Comment: No reason. Just to get the index, I guess you could use a in range() too, but I'm just used to this way.

Comment: You could have `list3.append(item + list2[index])` inside the loop so that `item` is used.

Comment: Precisely, I dont see any reason not to have item defined. Can be useful if he's doing something else later. I chose to to list1[index] because it's just more clear what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

for this or any two list of same size you may also use like this:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list3[i]=list1[i]+list2[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using zip

```
list3 = []
for l1,l2 in zip(list1,list2):
    list3.append(l1+l2)
```

`list3 = ['goodboy', 'badgirl', 'tallguy', 'bigman']`